# How to create a table with equally-spaced rows?

Tags: tables, spacing

Several years ago I succeeded to create a table below. But now I forgot. Maybe I used a `\rule` with zero width. Is there another smart method to accomplish this mission? I used `longtable` to make the table automatically span across pages, but any kind of table is welcome.

Requirements:

- 3 columns.
- 4 equally-spaced rows occupying `\textheight`.
- support displayed math contents such as `\[` or `\equation`.
- the table spans across pages automatically.

as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[draft]{article} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\def\xstrut{\rule[-0.125\textheight]{0pt}{\dimexpr0.25\textheight-0.5pt}}
\begin{document} 

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\xstrut}l|X|X|}\hline
1 & \[ \int_1^\infty \frac1x \mathrm{d}x \] & 2 \\\hline
2 & \[ \int_1^\infty \frac1x \mathrm{d}x \] & 2 \\\hline
3 & \[ \int_1^\infty \frac1x \mathrm{d}x \] & 2 \\\hline
4 & \[ \int_1^\infty \frac1x \mathrm{d}x \] & 2 \\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Herbert: just out of curiosity, why does your strut need the `[raise-height]` of `-0.125\textheight`?

Comment: @Brent: try it without and it should be obviously to you, right?

Comment: @Herbert: I stand justly rebuked for my laziness... I'm on the road, and only have an old out-of-date TexLive

Comment: @Herbert: OK, now I see, ausgezeichnet!

Comment: @Herbert: Can you make the table breakable across pages?

Comment: @Herbert -- won't this table be vertically overfull by the thickness of the 5 `\hlines`?  and wouldn't you want the first column aligned `r` in case the numbers increase in number of digits?

Comment: @Barbara: you are right, it is 5 x 0.4pt too high

Comment: @xport: it makes no difference to have it as a longtable. Use package `ltablex` and then `\LTXtable{\linewidth}{external file}` or one of the other tabular packages like `tabu`, `xtab`, ...

Comment: @Herbert: `\newlength{\halfheight}
\setlength{\halfheight}{\dimexpr(\textheight-2pt)/8\relax}
\def\xstrut{\rule[-\halfheight]{0pt}{2\halfheight}}`

Comment: @egreg: `\def\xstrut{\rule[-0.125\textheight]{0pt}{\dimexpr0.25\textheight-0.5pt}}`

Comment: @Herbert: This makes the cells sligthly asymmetric, however the difference is very small.

Comment: @Herbert: According to Martin, `\dimexpr` should be ended with `\relax`.

Comment: @xport: not only according to Martin. Leaving the `\relax` out is just as dangerous as defining `\quad` as `\hskip 1em`.

Comment: @Bruno: I cannot read it in the eTeX manual that it should _always_ be there ...

Comment: @Herbert: it does not have to be there, indeed, but `\dimexpr` will continue looking ahead for more to complete the expression. So at least you must know that something will indeed stop the dimension expression before it reaches other user input. For instance, if someone defined a special rule as `\def\myvrule#1{\vrule width 3pt height #1\relax}`, which is safe in TeX, using it as `\myvrule{\dimexpr 1pt+2sp} depth...` would break, as the `\relax` would be removed by `\dimexpr`, and `\vrule` would then look for a `depth` part.

Comment: ... in the case of `\rule`, all is fine, because `\setlength` is used internally, and includes `\relax` in its definition, which stops a possible `\dimexpr`.

Comment: @Herbert, @egreg: The shift should be `\rule[\dimexpr-0.125\textheight+0.25pt\relax]{0pt}{\dimexpr0.25\textheight-0.5pt\relax}`?